# Save current active tab after refresh

Tags: javascript, html

I have menu who change active class and apply underground style under it:

Snippet of my code:

```js
(function() {
  var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('tab');

  for (i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {

    tabs[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      removeActive();
      e.target.classList.add('active');
    })
  }
})();


function removeActive() {
  var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('tab');
  for (i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
    tabs[i].classList.remove('active')
  }
}
```

```css
 .myTabs {
   border: 1px solid #797979;
   background: #ffffff;
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #d6d6d6 100%);
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #d6d6d6 100%);
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%, #d6d6d6 100%);
   filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#d6d6d6', GradientType=0);
 }

 .myTabs a {
   color: #000000;
   border-left: 1px solid #797979;
   display: block;
   padding: 5px 10px;
   float: right;
   text-decoration: none;
 }

 .myTabs a:hover {
   background: #ffffff;
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d6d6d6 0%, #ffffff 100%);
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d6d6d6 0%, #ffffff 100%);
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d6d6d6 0%, #ffffff 100%);
   filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d6d6d6', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=0);
   text-decoration: none;
 }

 .myTabs a:active,
 .myTabs a:visited {
   text-decoration: none;
 }

 .myTabs a.active {
   /*box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px grey;*/
   background: #ffffff;
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c3c3c3 0%, #ffffff 100%);
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c3c3c3 0%, #ffffff 100%);
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c3c3c3 0%, #ffffff 100%);
   filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#c3c3c3', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=0);
   text-decoration: none;
 }
```

```html
 <div class="myTabs">
         <div style="float:left; margin:5px;">
           Load
          </div>
           <a href="#bonos" class="tab" aria-controls="bonos" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">tab3<a>
           <a href="#empleados" class="tab" aria-controls="empleados" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">tab2</a>
           <a href="#puestos" class="active tab" aria-controls="puestos" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">tab1</a>
                        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                    </div>
```

That I want to achieve is for example if my current tab is "Tab3" and I refresh page. keep with Tab3 instead refresh all and return Tab1 again.

What I need to do to achieve this? Regards

Answer (score 1):

There is two different ways, one is a cookie and the other is localstorage. For something like this I would use localstorage so you arent sending the activetab per request. However, some browsers/computer dont support localStorage so you can use the cookie code above.

Below is a JS Fiddle of localStorage that also saves the active tab.

Any questions feel free to ask.

[JSFiddle - LocalStorage](https://jsfiddle.net/74sh2Lfb/11/)

Here is part of the code:

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
   if (localStorage.lastTab == undefined) localStorage.setItem("lastTab",0);
   var i = localStorage.lastTab;
   $('.fakeTabs > li').removeClass('active').eq(i).addClass('active');
} else {
   // This will not save an active tab unless you use cookies but why waste the space.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using document.cookies to save  data after a refresh:

[How to use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)

When updating the active tab do

```
document.cookie = “activeTab=“ + activeTab
```

And when the page loads try to retrieve this data:

```
var activeTab = document.cookie.split(“=“);
if(activeTab.length == 2) {
    activeTab = activeTab[1]:
} else {
    activeTab = “1”;
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: I should use it in new function?

Comment: @Pepe the first code is to save activeTab, the second code is to get activeTab after the page is loaded/refreshed. That should be run at the beginning to set an active tab.

Comment: it just return "undefined" cookie

Comment: @Pepe cookies don’t work on local files, it has to be on the internet for it to work. You can however test it by using document.cookietest and assigning the value yourself.